# Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /predict/ Exception Value: 'a'

Tags: django

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /predict/
Exception Value: 'a'

Code

val1 = float(request.GET['a'])

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use  `dict.get(KEY_NAME)` because it returns another value if the key doesn't exist
also try to print it to see what in it

```py
print(request.GET)
```